# Github action pointing to a different directory than the current directory

Tags: github, github-actions

When running an action during a pull request the path emitted by `mkdir` while trying to create a folder was different than the current directory set by a previous step. This also continues to the next steps as follows..

```
name: Publish demo
on: 
  push:
    branches:    
      - 'develop'
  pull_request:
    branches:    
      - 'develop'
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1

    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.1.1
      
    - name: Navigate to Workspace
      run: cd ${{ github.workspace }}/demo_project

    - name: Create Build Directory
      run: mkdir _build
      
    - name: Restore Packages
      run: nuget restore demo_project.csproj

    - name: Build Solution
      run: |
        msbuild.exe demo_project.csproj /nologo /nr:false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:PublishUrl="_build"
    - name: Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
      with:
        local-dir: "_build"
        server: <server>
        username: <username>
        password: ${{ secrets.password }}
```

So, in this line..

```
      run: mkdir _build
```

the `_build` folder should be created in `demo_project` but instead it gets created in `${{ github.workspace }}` which i think means that setting the current directory here..

```
      run: cd ${{ github.workspace }}/demo_project
```

which in turn prints out this in job view..

```
Run cd D:\a\demo_solution\demo_solution/demo_project
```

and..

```
Input file does not exist: D:\demo_project.csproj.
```

did not take effect. So, what am i missing?

Comment: As you've seen, that doesn't persist between steps. Make a multi-line command or just set the appropriate working directory, both shown in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could specify a [different working directory](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun) for a job:

> You can provide default shell and working-directory options for all run steps in a job

```
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}/demo_project
    steps:
    - name: Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Comment: If i may ask, would it be possible to change the `working-directory` between steps?

Comment: you could set `working-directory` also for a single step adding the attribute